# Angular 2 searching for (Add item, remove item, select all items to array) dependancy

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to have a normal dependancy which lets add/remove items to array on item click, selects all - and then remove on click which you dont want.

For example :

Item List in ngFor :

button(Select all Items). (If selected all, button(Item) will remove only that button.

button(item) - On first click add, on second remove.

button(item) - On first click add, on second remove.

button(item) - On first click add, on second remove.

button(item) - On first click add, on second remove.

Added Items should have "Active" class.

**Anyone know similar dependancies of these functionalities ?**

My example (only delete item class css doesnt work if I select all and click on it) :

**TS :**

```
 myDist: Districts[] = [];
  buttActive = false;
   clicked = false;
  disableBtn = false;
 minus = false;
 allClicked = false;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
              public dataService: DistricSearchProvider,
              public events: Events) {

}


clickedB(i, item){
    item.clicked = !item.clicked;
    console.log(item.clicked)
  this.ifAll(i,item)
}

clickedAll(){
    this.allClicked = !this.allClicked;
}

//if item clicked first time
  changeActive(item, i){
    if(item.clicked === true && this.allClicked == false) {
      item.buttActive = !item.buttActive;
      this.addDistrict(item)
      console.log('Pridedam')
    }

    //if Item clicked second time
 else if(item.clicked === false && this.allClicked == false  ) {
      item.buttActive = !item.buttActive;
      this.deleteDistrict(item);
    }

  }
ifAll(i,item){
  if (this.allClicked == true) {
    console.log('If all worked')
    const i = this.myDist.indexOf(item.name);
    this.myDist.splice(i, 1);
    console.log(this.myDist)
    item.buttActive = !item.buttActive;
    item.allClicked = !item.allClicked;
    console.log('Mygtukas :', item.buttActive, item.allClicked)
  }
}
//add or delete district from the new array
  addDistrict(item){
    console.log('Item:', item)
this.disable = 'disabled';
   this.myDist.push(item.name)
    console.log('Pridėta',this.myDist)
  }

  deleteDistrict(item) {
   const index = this.myDist.indexOf(item.name)
    if (index !== -1) {
     console.log('Indexas :',index);
      this.myDist.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log('Deleted', this.myDist)
  }

 chooseAll(){
    if(this.allClicked == true) {
      this.myDist = this.dataService.items;
      this.disableBtn = !this.disableBtn;
      console.log(this.myDist)
    }

    else {
      this.myDist = new Array;
      this.disableBtn = !this.disableBtn;
    }

  }
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<button (click)="clickedAll();chooseAll()" ion-button class="choose-all">Choose all</button>

   <button [ngClass]="{'activeBtn': item.buttActive, 'activeBtnAll': allClicked, 'deleteArrayItem': minus }"
            (click)="clickedB(i, item);changeActive(item,i);"
            *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
            ion-button class="tag-btn">{{item.name}}
    </button>
```

**CSS :**

```
.activeBtn {
  background-color: #0045a4 !important;
  color:#fff !important;
}

  .activeBtnAll {
    background-color: #0045a4 !important;
    color:#fff !important;
  }

  .deleteArrayItem {
    background:red !important; //this doesnt really work
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the complexly here ?

Comment: I made everything by myself, just can't end this. And I think I made it more complex then it should be.

Comment: well, in order to actully help we gonna need code.

Comment: One moment. Will insert the code.

Comment: Sunil Singh , if thats so simple still got no answer :D

Answer (score 0):

In your deleteDistrict function you are only deleting only a single item and you want to delete all of them if clicked selectAll

You can do something like:

```
  deleteDistrict(item) {
    const index = this.myDist.indexOf(item.name);
   if(this.allClicked) {
     this.myDist.splice(this.myDist.length);
   }

  if (index !== -1) {
    console.log('Indexas :',index);
    this.myDist.splice(index, 1);
   }
   console.log('Deleted', this.myDist)
  }
```

Comment: I want to delete only one on click.

Comment: And My ifAll function does it.